# Ошибка API telegram + aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, node-telegram-bot-api

ребят. Возникла такая проблема с aiogram. Хочу получить от пользователя группу фотографий и после этого отправить её обратно с дополнительной информацией. Но бот в место того что бы отправить 3 фотографии после того как принял 3. отправляет 3 группы по 4 фотографии.
Смотрел айди фотографий при приеме там не 3 разных айди, а 4 одинаковых.
Спрашивал на других форумах, те проверяли на других библиотеках, говорят, это ошибка API.
Есть ли обходные пути?

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO, state=CREATEPOSTFSM.Photo_state)
async def process_photos_step(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    photos: List[types.PhotoSize] = message.photo
    await state.update_data(photos=photos)
    data = await state.get_data()
    photos = data.get('photos')
    caption = data.get('Info_state')
    media_group = [InputMediaPhoto(photo.file_id) for photo in photos]
    await message.answer(f'Название продукта: {data.get("Name_state")}')
    await message.answer('Вот как будет выглядеть ваш пост:')
    await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=message.chat.id, media=media_group)
    await state.finish()
```